# Create date range using recursive function won't return values

Tags: python, datetime, recursion, return

I am trying to build a function that creates a list of start and end dates. I am implementing it using a recursive function. Problem is my list isn't returned. When I run the code below:

```py
from dateutil import parser

def dateinterval(listing_date, dates=[]):
    period = 1000

    dates.append(listing_date)
    base = parser.parse(listing_date)
    next_date = base + datetime.timedelta(days=period)
    dates.append(next_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    if base > datetime.datetime.now():
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        print dates
        return dates
    dateinterval(next_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), dates)


a = dateinterval('2017-01-01')
print(a)
```

I get the following result:

```py
['2017-01-01', '2019-09-28', '2019-09-28', '2022-06-24', '2022-06-24', '2025-03-20', '2025-03-20', '2027-12-15', '2022-10-03']
None
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to return your dates.

Comment: what is `parser.parse` method does ? Or you could give more information about your desired output.

Comment: @quamrana isn’t it enough to return the dates within the if-statement?

Comment: No. You should study the principles of recursive functions first. There is the base case and the recursive case. Both need to return.

Comment: @RahulKP I edited the post so it includes my imports.

Comment: @quamrana aha! I thought it was enough to make a function call. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I will study the recursive case.